# Facebook Automated Data Collection for an ios app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, app-store

I built an ios app that uses web scraping for data collection from facebook. After submitting the app to appstore I got a reply to provide documentary evidence for scraping. After searching alot on internet I found no link to contact facebook for permission. The only web link to permission form

https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos.php

is broken and not working.

I have read the Facebook's Automated Data Collection Terms and my app doesn't violate any of these terms.
The only problem I have is to get permission from Facebook as they state in
term 2 of Automated Data Collection Terms  i.e. 2. 'You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission'.

Can anybody guide me about how to get permission from facebook.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with programming

Comment: What data are you scraping?

Comment: scraping Ids of friends who liked a post by the user.

Comment: Use the API. And if it is not available in the API then Facebook doesn't want you to do it

Comment: But there is this link that allows you scrap data but you have to get permission. https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Correct. You will not get permission for it.

Comment: Can you tell me WHY?

Comment: If they wanted you to do it it would be available in the API

Comment: So, how to get permission for scrapping data that are available in the API?